Как узнать какие технологии использует сервер сайта?
Есть ли способы узнать, какие техногогии использует сервер сайта? Предположим что он отдаеться с Cloudflare и там на прямую скрыта эта информация. Как ещё можно получить информацию о сайте?  Что-то по типу wappalyzer проанализировать сайт не дает.
*Сайт, разумеется чужой, и спрашивать не у кого.
К примеру веб портал - https://www.uaportal.com/ (С головы, просто сайт тоже с Cloudflare)

о каких технологиях речь?

Серверных... как минимум Node.js или Apache а так любая информация.

в общем случае - никак. Добавь сайт, который ты хотел проверить

Добавил. По косвенным признакам по типу использована библиотека Express значит точно Node.js, как-то звучит плохо. Хотелось бы более конкретное решение

нет, так не получится, косвенные признаки они потому и косвенные, что могут на что угодно указывать.
